# ¿En Python 3.6 y Pyqt5 cómo obtener un dato que se generó en un Widget?

Tags: python, pyqt5

En mi Script principal quiero obtener un dato que se generó en un Widget ¿Cómo le puedo hacer?

el código de mi Widget wid_year.py es

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Set Year'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.initUI()

      def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.getDate()
        self.show()

    def getDate(self):
        i, okPressed = QInputDialog.getInt(self, "Select a Year","Year:", 2018, 2013, 2030  , 1)
        if okPressed:
            print("el dato dentro del Widget es ",i)
            return i


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

y el código del script principal es:

```
import wid_year
year = wid_year.App()
print("el dato en el script principal es :",year)
```

Ale ejecutar el script principal el resultado obtenido es:

```
el dato dentro del Widget es 2018
el dato en el script principal es : <wid_year.App object at 0x0000029F07D3EB88>
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilicé la siguiente línea de código:

```
import wid_year
year = wid_year.App.getDate(self)
print("el dato en el script principal es :",year)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

main_script.py

```
# main_script
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from main_module import main
    main()
```

main_module.py

```
# main_module
import sys
from PyQt5 import Qt

import other_module

class App(Qt.QMainWindow): 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.label = Qt.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("""QLabel{
          font-family:'Consolas'; 
          color: red; 
          font-size: 20px;}""")
        self.label.setGeometry(10, 20, 500, 50)
        self.setGeometry(400, 200, 600, 300)

        self.some_function()  

    def some_function(self):
        import other_module
        year = other_module.getDate(self)     
        self.label.setText("el dato en el script principal es : {}".format(year))        
        print("el dato en el script principal es :", year)


def main():
    app = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = App()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

other_module.py

```
# other_module
from PyQt5 import Qt
import main_module

def getDate(self):
    i, okPressed = Qt.QInputDialog.getInt(self, "Select a Year","Year:", 2018, 2013, 2030  , 1)
    if okPressed:
        print("el dato dentro del Widget es ",i)
        return i
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]